# Custom Serialization in ASP.NET MVC API

Tags: serialization, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Position 
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming a data contract similar to this one:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyModel
{
    [DataMember(name="position")]
    public Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

I want to send this position value both ***to*** and ***from*** the client using a value like this:

JSON: `{ "position": "1,2" }`

XML: `<position>1,2</position>`

I'll just add that I'm not trying to do this:

JSON: `{ "position": { "data": "1,2" } }`

XML: `<position><data>1,2</data></position>`

I'd rather not inject this into the whole serialization pipeline if possible. I had it working on a web controller, but the API controller is proving a little tricky.  What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Decided in this case to use the position fields as is (e.g. `{ "position": { "X": 1, "Y": 2 } }`), but I'll leave this open and update it if I come across a solution.

Comment: How did you get it working on the standard MVC controller?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a view model:

```
[DataContract]
public class PositionViewModel
{
    [DataMember(name = "position")]
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

and then map between your `Position` domain model and your view model in the controller action if needed.